# Download object from GCP's Storage using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I'm using [@google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) to access objects inside a Google Cloud Storage bucket from a node application, but I can't make it work.

I've created a Service Account on the GCP's console, and assigned the **Storage Admin** role to it, but when I try to get a file I get this message:

> service-account-user@my-project-5411148.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to my-bucket-45826813215/some-object.

Looking at the bucket's permissions tab, I can see the service account is listed there with the *inherited* annotation and I haven't set any specific permissions to the objects.

My code looks like this:

```js
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const config = require('./config');
const storage = new Storage({ 'keyFilename': config.configFullPath('gcloud') });

const privateBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket-45826813215'); 

let objectDownload = async (filename) => {
    let file = privateBucket.file(filename);
    let result = await file.download();
    return result;
}

objectDownload('some-object')
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Done');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am able to download the file with a `Storage Admin Role`. Below are the process which I  followed

**1. Create Project**
[image]

**2. Go to IAM and select service account**

[image]

**3. Select create-service account**
[image]

**4. select role for service account**
[image]

**5. Create key**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Below is working code:**

```
const path = require('path');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');


async function test() {

const serviceKey = path.join(__dirname, './keys.json')


const storageConf = {keyFilename:serviceKey}

const storage = new Storage(storageConf)

const downlaodOptions = {
      destination: __dirname+'/test.jpg'
    };

    try {
    let res =await storage
      .bucket('storage1232020')
      .file('test.jpg')
      .download(downlaodOptions); 
   }
   catch(err){
    console.log(err)
   }

}

test()
```

**Note**:  Make sure

1. The service account and bucket be created under a project. For example, I created a bucket and service account for project **storage-dem01232020**
2. You are passing key properly to code

**Ways to download file**

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

const file = myBucket.file('my-file');

//-
// Download a file into memory. The contents will be available as the
second
// argument in the demonstration below, `contents`.
//-
file.download(function(err, contents) {});

//-
// Download a file to a local destination.
//-
file.download({
  destination: '/Users/me/Desktop/file-backup.txt'
}, function(err) {});

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
file.download().then(function(data) {
  const contents = data[0];
});
```

Refer below link for more detials:
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download

Comment: Is there a way to download the file into memory instead of to a temp directory? For instance, to save the file from the bucket into a variable?

Comment: updating the answer.