# How to download file from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm following up on this article to download objects from GCP Cloud storage bucket: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function downloadIntoMemory() {
  // Downloads the file into a buffer in memory.
  const contents = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download();

 return contents;
  );
}

downloadIntoMemory().catch(console.error);
```

I'm currently getting a buffer data in `contents`. I've this code hooked upto a API on NodeJS backend. I'm using React Typescript on frontend. Calling the API, gives me data buffer. How can I use it to download the file instead of the data buffer?

I tried the above method explicitly providing file destination, but I'm still getting the following error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '{file_path_which_i_was_set}. Err: -21

Comment: Your link provides an example that downloads the Cloud Storage object to a file on the same machine that the code is running on. Just add the **options** parameter: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59865677/download-object-from-gcps-storage-using-nodejs/59884875#59884875

Comment: You use react typescript frontend and it works? Be sure to test your code in a clean sandbox without any env variable set.

Comment: @JohnHanley I want to set destFileName dynamically. How can I set file destination in React?

Comment: Your original question has been answered. For new questions, create a new post.

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried the above method explicitly providing file destination, but I'm still getting the following error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '{file_path_which_i_was_set}. Err: 21

Comment: Sorry it says errno: -21

Comment: Edit your question with what you tried and the complete error message.

Answer (score 2):

As rightly pointed out by @John Hanley, you are referring to the documentation, where the code sample downloads an object into memory/ buffer in memory. If you want to download an object from a bucket to a file, refer to this [code sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#downloading-an-object), where the ‘options’ parameter has to be passed to the download() method.
The code goes like this :

```
// The ID of your GCS bucket
const bucketName = 'your-unique-bucket-name';

// The ID of your GCS file
const fileName = 'your-file-name';

// The path to which the file should be downloaded
const destFileName = '/local/path/to/file.txt';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function downloadFile() {
  const options = {
    destination: destFileName,
  };

  // Downloads the file to the destination file path
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download(options);

  console.log(
    `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName} downloaded to ${destFileName}.`
  );
}

downloadFile().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I want to set destFileName dynamically. How can I set destination in React?

Comment: I tried the above method explicitly providing file destination, but I'm still getting the following error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '{file_save_path}. Err: 21

Comment: EISDIR stands for "Error, Is Directory". This means you are trying to do something to a file but it is a directory. 

1.Make sure the file exists. If it does not, you need to create it. 
2.Make sure it is in fact a file and not a directory.

Comment: Regarding the EISDIR error, `destination` needs to be the path including the new file name of the file you are downloading: `path/to/myfile.txt` etc, not the directory where to download it to.