# Uploading file to Google Cloud Storage results in empty file

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to handle a file upload from an HTTP POST request via a Google Cloud Function, and store the file on a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The file does *appear* to upload successfully, and in the console it shows the correct file size, but when I try to view the file it's broken, and when I download it, it has zero bytes.

Here's my Google Cloud Function:

```
const packageObj = require('./package.json');
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

functions.http('main', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const file = req.body;
    const bucketName = 'MY_BUCKET_NAME';
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
    const f = storage.bucket(bucketName).file('test.jpg');
    f.save(file).then(() => {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(
        {
          version: packageObj.version,
          message: 'File uploaded!'
        },
        null,
        2
      ));
    });
  }
});
```

Since I'm using functions-framework, I run `functions-framework --target=main`, and then do:

`curl -F 'data=@test/resources/car_image.jpg' http://localhost:8080/main`

(I've also tested by deploying the function itself, to rule out functions-framework, but I get the same result.)

In the console, the file size shows as 62.9KB, which is the size of the test image I'm uploading:

[image: Screenshot of Google Cloud Console showing file size as 62.9KB]

But when I use the download feature from the console, I end up with a file with 0 bytes. And the preview of the file in the console is broken.

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you try `const file = req.file;`  instead of `req.body`  and also look this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59884875/18265570)

Comment: @RoopaM `req.file` is `undefined`. `req` has both `.body` and `.rawBody` properties, both of which are of type `<Buffer>` when I write the request out to to the console.

Comment: Regarding the other thread, I'm using the owner account in the Google Cloud Console to download the file, so I should have permission. (I'm able to manually upload and download other images via the console without issue.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that when you do a file upload via HTTP POST (similar to an HTML form), the `req.body` is actually `multipart/form-data`. So you have to parse that and extract just the file data.

This wasn't immediately obvious because I was saving as a `.jpg`. The way I found it out was to save it out to a `.txt` file instead, which instead of being empty began with:

```
--------------------------f88ab613f89b5970
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="car_image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

The [Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-form-data) recommend using the [Busboy package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) to parse `multipart/form-data`, which streams the raw body. Since it streams it, you have to convert it to a single Buffer with the `Buffer.concat()` method.

Here's the complete solution:

```
const packageObj = require('./package.json');
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const Busboy = require('busboy');

functions.http('main', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else if (req.method === 'POST') {

    const busboy = Busboy({headers: req.headers});

    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, {filename}) => {
      if (fieldname === 'data') {
        let chunks = [];
        file.on('data', data => {
          chunks.push(data);
        });

        file.on('end', () => {
          const bucketName = 'plate-scan-images';
          const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
          const f = storage.bucket(bucketName).file('test.jpg');
          f.save(Buffer.concat(chunks)).then(() => {
            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(
              {
                version: packageObj.version,
                message: 'File uploaded!'
              },
              null,
              2
            ));
          });
        });
      }

    });

    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
  }
});
```